# Decompile C# vs C++

Tags: c#, c++, decompiling

I have read many posts about decompiling (though no experience) but did not understand why all of them generally mentioned that it is easier to decompile C# than C++ executable.  Could anyone explain the difference?

Comment: See also answers to [this question](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/311/60).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C# compiles into [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), not directly into a native code like a C++ compiler would normally do.

It produces a [*.NET assembly*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assembly_%28CLI%29), which contains much more meta data than a C++ executable does (via the embedded [manifest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifest_%28CLI%29)) - this is metadata about the types contained in the assembly, what it references and more, making it much easier to decompile than a "normal" executable.

As noted in the comments, CIL in and of itself is a higher level language than assembly and is an object oriented language, making it easier to understand and decompile correctly.

Comment: As a sidenote, .NET `assembly` and `assembly language` are totally separate things :-)

Comment: IMO, the single most important difference is that CIL is still object oriented while machine language is not.

Comment: Also: pretty much the entire structure of C# classes can be reflected, which makes decompilation much easier because you only need to decompile the CIL in the function bodies

Answer (score 0):

It's simply.
The C#-code has necessary information for restore source code, but C/C++ hasn't it.